# Restrict Portrait for iPad Air and iPad Air 2

Tags: ios, ipad, air

Using Xcode 7 and iOS 9.0 simulator.  I would like my specific view controller to only be in portrait.  My code is as follows:

`override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}`

This works in simulator for every device iPhone 4/5/5s/6/6s/plus/Splus iPad 2, iPad retina etc.  For some reason it doesn't work on iPad Air or iPad Air 2.  Does this make any sense?

Comment: do you have add the supported interface orientations in info.plist file?

Comment: In the info.plist we have all the interface orientations supported.  We need this for two reasons... 1) we'd like to use the new split screen feature (and this is necessary for that) and 2) we have specific UIViewControllers we'd like to use all orientations and some we only want to have Portrait.